# How do I get only one row after using Max function, when another field has different values?

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I am using this code:

```
select row1, row2, max(row3) as max_row3 from table
group by row1, row2
order by row1
```

My output looks like this:

```
row1    row2    max_row3
A       123     29.27 <-- Max for A
A       456     5.86
B       123     34.46
B       456     25.82
B       789     59.46 <-- Max for B
```

I want it to look like the below:

```
row1    row2    max_row3
A       123     29.27
B       789     59.46
```

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: You have labelled your columns "row" which is quite confusing.  I also removed the incompatible database tags.

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col3 desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.row3 = (
    select max(t1.row3) from mytable t1 where t1.row1 = t.row1 and t1.row2 = t.row2
)
```

For performance with this query, you want an index on `(row1, row2, row3)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to identify the data you want:

```
select *  
from (
  select
    *,
    row_number() over(partition by row1 order by row3 desc) as rn
  from t
) x
where rn = 1
```